# Trying to connect to sqlite file using constructor

Tags: sqlite

```
include ("db.php");
    $db = new CMSDB();
    if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cases (case_id, case_type, priority, postalCode, status, location) VALUES (NULL, 'pending', 'low', 33, 'help', 'singapore')";

        if($db->exec($sql) == TRUE){
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }

        else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
        }
```

//Cant seem to connect to the database with the constructor
//Cant seem to connect to the database with the constructor

//Cant seem to connect to the database with the constructor

```
    class CMSDB extends SQLite3{
     function __construct(){
      $this->open('DB.sqlite');
    }
 }
```

This is the Database constructor.

Comment: Ok, and? What is your question?

Comment: The query doesnt run and enter else @vasan

Comment: @Vasan yup. It enters else. Should I be using PDO instead?